# how to add crop option to image pick

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this code

```
Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            getIntent.setType("image/*");

            Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            pickIntent.setType("image/*");

            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select Image");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {pickIntent});
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 1);
```

what should I add to make crop after getting the image

Answer (score 0):

You should add [a library to your project that handles image cropping](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45), then use that library with the image that you get back from your `startActivityForResult()` call.

[Android does not have an image-cropping `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html), and there is no requirement for any activity that honors `ACTION_PICK`, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to support some undocumented extras to handle image cropping for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have like this

```
 private void doCrop() {
        final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setType("image/*");

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
                intent, 0);

        int size = list.size();

        if (size == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        } else {
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

            intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            if (size == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

                i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                        res.activityInfo.name));

                startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
            } else {
                for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                    final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                    co.title = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(
                            res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(
                            res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);

                    co.appIntent
                            .setComponent(new ComponentName(
                                    res.activityInfo.packageName,
                                    res.activityInfo.name));

                    cropOptions.add(co);
                }

                CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(
                        getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
                builder.setAdapter(adapter,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                                startActivityForResult(
                                        cropOptions.get(item).appIntent,
                                        CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                            }
                        });

                builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                            getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null,
                                    null);
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Adapter class

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.content.Context;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CropOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CropOption> {
    private ArrayList<CropOption> mOptions;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CropOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CropOption> options) {
        super(context, R.layout.crop_selector, options);

        mOptions    = options;

        mInflater   = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup group) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.crop_selector, null);

        CropOption item = mOptions.get(position);

        if (item != null) {
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon)).setImageDrawable(item.icon);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name)).setText(item.title);

            return convertView;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Adapter xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```

pojo class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class CropOption {
    public CharSequence title;
    public Drawable icon;
    public Intent appIntent;
}
```

Comment: i have done every thing but it tells me when retrieving Uri from data it is null

Comment: any idea why i;m getting null?